# Restoring an Overmodulated Analog Phone Recording

Tags: audio-restoration, broadcast, phone

Analogue phone lines are limited in bandwidth therefore also somewhat iimited in possible adjustments. While such recordings can not and are not meant to be presented in full fidelity, there are possibilities of improving their comprehensibility especially for broadcast scenarios.

[This artifact-full and heavily distorted recording](https://soundcloud.com/sumskijoze/analogue-phone-overmodulation) is a result of both over modulation on the phone line itself (probably due to interoperability of digital and analog lines with differing codecs, transmission standards, ..) and the end-of-chain broadcast processing by an Omnia processor.

What tactics would you employ to soften the harsh "humming artifact"? It seems to span in both the 100 - 300 Hz and 1,4 - 1,7 kHz. A notch filter helps, but only improves the low end.

Comment: Hi L.C. What on earth are those harsh sounds whenever the voice is heard? I did a quick(5 mins) tidy up([here](https://soundcloud.com/n00dlz/analogue-phone-overmodulation-quicktidyup-audition)) in Audition(I'm on my laptop atm), but without an isolated sample of this noise, it would be hard to attenuate without affecting the (albeit limited) frequencies of the speech.

Comment: As said, the harsh sounds are a combination of master output processing and distortion on the phone line itself (pre-anything). This is not environmental noise, rather something that occurs electronically. Albeit my results being similar to yours the employed procedure would be great to read for further reference. 

If anyone has ideas about the source of the problem - noise on the line - please do add your 5 cents.